# How to hide and show a div with coffeescript - Rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

I am trying to make a similar behavior as the comment link on a question in Stack Overflow.
A click should hide the div containing the "Add comment" link and show another div containing the form for a new comment.

How is it possible to do that with coffeescript ?

I am trying the following that does not work :

```
jQuery ->

  hide_comment_link = () ->
    $('#add_comment_link').hide
  hide_comment = () ->
    $('#add_comment').hide
  show_comment = () ->
    $('#add_comment').show

  $('#add_comment_link').click ->
    hide_comment_link
    show_comment
    false
```

View is :

```
#add_comment_link
  #{link_to "Add a comment"}
#add_comment
  Add a comment in this div.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unlike Ruby, CoffeeScript doesn't allow you to omit parentheses from function/method calls if there are no arguments. You need to add them:

```
$('#add_comment_link').hide()
```

```
hide_comment_link()
```

The `do` keyword is another option:

```
do $('#add_comment_link').hide
```

```
do hide_comment_link
```

Comment: Many thanks! I feel so unconfortable fot that silly question. Well, I hope this will be helpful for other developers...

Answer (score 5):

I believe the problem here is a lack of parentheses:

```
hide_comment_link = () ->
  $('#add_comment_link').hide()
hide_comment = () ->
  $('#add_comment').hide()
show_comment = () ->
  $('#add_comment').show()

$('#add_comment_link').click ->
  hide_comment_link()
  show_comment()
  false
```

Edit: @Jeremy beat me to it